# How to click a link inside a carousel in selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, carousel

See this link: https://bluelinetourpackage.com/Web
Inside there is a KNOW MORE button which inside a carsouel every time I take the xpath and click using selenium java it won't do anything. Anyone please help I'm a student learning selenium java

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/section[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]")).click();
```

This is my code to click the link it is not working

I took the xpath and put in the findelement code but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use full xpathes, it's bad practice. Try to use unique locators that point to your element instead.

In you case carousel has several items. Item's class is `carousel-item`.
When item appears in viewport, it gets additional class `active`.
So locator for current visible item is `.carousel-item.active`.

The only thing that left is button locator. Button is actually single `a` in container with some `href`.

Now we got full unique locator of active item and it is `.carousel-item.active a[href]`

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
driver.get("https://bluelinetourpackage.com/Web");

WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".carousel-item.active a[href]")));
button.click();
```

Comment: Worked for me with few adjustments the code works for older version of selenium. For newer version it will be:    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
   driver.get("https://bluelinetourpackage.com/Web");

   WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".carousel-item.active a[href]")));
   button.click();[/codeblock]